# What is the output length of CBC with zero input?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, des

Given this formula for CBC encryption from [6.2 The Cipher Block Chaining Mode](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf)

[image: C_1 = CIPH_K(P_1 ⊕ IV); C_j = CIPH_K(P_j ⊕ C_(j-1)) for j = 2 ... n]

what is the output length of CBC if plaintext `P` is of length 0?

Comment: It is a block cipher - so it would involve padding - so the length of P would never be 0. So I believe the Cipher size should be exactly equal to one block size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block ciphers like CBC require an input as multiple of the block size. In this case P would need to be padded to be one block long.

Another thing to notice is that the first block of P is being XORed with the IV which is also one block long - this will also ensure that you start with an input data of size which is at least one block long.

Being a block cipher your output will be the same size as input (excluding any communications for IV between sender and receiver).

Comment: By *multiple of the block size* you mean a *non-zero multiple of the block size*, right? So it is safe to declare 0 as an invalid input length of block cipher modes (like CBC) and padding needs to respect that?

Comment: Yes that is correct @SimonWarta. The minimum being one block size due to padding (and indirectly by XORing with one block sized IV).

Comment: Thanks a lot! You just supported the Botan C++11 crypto library by sharing that insight :)

Comment: @SimonWarta, That is wonderful to know! How do I find out - if I could contribute more actively to the project?

Comment: To be precise, you confirmed that my fix in round_up() towards mathematically correct rounding can be done because length must not be 0 in occurrence 7. 8. and 9.: https://github.com/randombit/botan/commit/7f3c4b1ab3837e75e890232bd2c3ecb9f6390732?diff=unified
There is a lot more to do, including long term discussions about cryptography. I'd love to see you contributing with knowledge or code: https://github.com/randombit/botan/issues